# Setting UINavigationBar globally?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change `UINavigationBar` instances globally with the code below which is in the `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(:_)`;

```
let navBarApp = UINavigationBar.appereance()
navBarApp.barTintColor = UIColor.mmtRed
```

but the result is;

[image: figure1]

as you can see from the picture, colors are different which meant to be same. (The buttons' color is the one that I want my navigation bar to have.)

When I add the code as follows:

```
navBarApp.isTranslucent = false
```

the result is;

[image: figure2]

The colors are same right now but there is a weird gap between `UINavigationBar` and `mainView`. So How can I solve it? Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Forgot the mention that I am using a library [PageMenu](http://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) maybe this has some kind of an effect?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` Set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`.

Comment: root's `viewDidLoad`or navigationController's ?

Comment: tried both and didn't work

Comment: In root's `viewDidLiad`

Comment: Try this in rootViewController's viewDidLoad `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []`

Comment: did not work also

Comment: self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false. Try this in viewController having tableView not in root or navigation controller

Comment: did not work either, If you have any ideas to get the right color on navigation bar without `isTranslucent = false` maybe these will work.

Comment: You can set backgroundimage instead

Comment: I will try that, gonna inform you afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` in `viewDidLoad()`of viewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

or better make sure, Adjust Scroll View insets are unticked in all controllers

[image]

If set in rootViewController make sure this property is not overwritten in child controllers

**Update :**

The above solution should work in most scenarios, or you can set backGroundImage instead of making bar translucent as given in @WilsonXJ answer.

You can use a extension

```
extension UIImage {
   static func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        tintColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Use this as

```
navBarApp.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(tintColor: <Custom color>), for: .default)
```

Comment: yeah I just tried it, and sadly did not work. I also check this option in navigationController, it was already unticked

Comment: you checked in  all controllers, including UIViewControllers?

Comment: I am using a library  (https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) maybe this has some kind of an effect?

Comment: Not sure, I have not used this library. I will c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129254/discussion-between-faruk-and-dili).

Comment: I have put a solution in chat try :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
UIColor.redColor().setFill()// your color
UIRectFill(rect)
let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

it works for me

Comment: colours do not match for this method

Comment: @Faruk did you change the color

Comment: @Faruk  change redcolor to your color and try